# What is the best practice for indicating multiple player types for a VideoObject in Schema.org?

Tags: metadata, schema.org, microdata, video-player

I am adding Schema.org Microdata to a video page using the [`VideoObject` schema](http://schema.org/VideoObject).

The video player at this company is still using Flash as their default player (it's feature rich) and HTML as a fallback. While this is to continue to be the case until mid 2017 I need to indicate the player type appropriately in the metadata.

The front end checks if Flash is available at the required version and if so will inject the Flash player in the page. Alternatively it will inject the HTML version of the player.

Is the following valid? The testing tool doesn't complain but there is no indication in the docs if this is a valid value.

```html
<meta itemprop="playerType" content="Flash, HTML5" />
```

Or would I be better off indicating HTML as this would likely be the preferred format for indexing and is definitely available if a little less fully featured?

```html
<meta itemprop="playerType" content="HTML5" />
```

Presumably a crawler may not have access to Flash and so will see the HTML5 player on the page anyway.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the explicit meta `itemProp` property via the logic that you are using to inject the correct player?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can’t convey with the [`playerType` property](http://schema.org/playerType) that the value represents a list of alternatives. Something like "Flash, HTML5" could mean that Flash *and* HTML5 are required, which isn’t the case. Using only "HTML5" doesn’t seem to be appropriate either, because (I guess) the Flash version doesn’t require HTML5 support.

As [`VideoObject`](http://schema.org/VideoObject) is defined to represent a video *file*, one solution might be to provide two `VideoObject` items. Then each could have its own [`contentSize`](http://schema.org/contentSize), [`encodingFormat`](http://schema.org/encodingFormat), [`playerType`](http://schema.org/playerType) etc.

To convey that these `VideoObject` items represent the same video, you could introduce a [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) item (or the more specific [`Clip`](http://schema.org/Clip), [`Episode`](http://schema.org/Episode), or [`Movie`](http://schema.org/Movie), if applicable) that holds metadata about the video that’s the same for both video files (e.g., [`about`](http://schema.org/about), [`description`](http://schema.org/description), [`director`](http://schema.org/director) etc.).

This item can then be used as value for the [`encodesCreativeWork`](http://schema.org/encodesCreativeWork) property.

So it could look like this in Microdata:

```html
<div itemprop="encodesCreativeWork" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Clip" id="work">
  <p itemprop="description" id="work-description">…</p>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject" itemref="work work-description">
  <meta itemprop="playerType" content="Flash" />
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject" itemref="work work-description">
  <meta itemprop="playerType" content="HTML" />
</div>
```

That’s the theory. If a consumer actually expects/supports this is a different question.